# Cut out/burn in DEM along street polyline with different heigth, width and elevation of the cut

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

I have a task to do and can’t seem to find the right tools for the job. Below you can see two graphics to demonstrate my task.

I need to cut off/out some parts of a DEM to unearth several street segments from a tunnel. It’s almost like burning streams into a DEM but more complex.

[image]

The cut has to follow a predefined polyline (blue) from P1 to P2, with all the nodes at different elevations (see image below) and lower the DEM to the street level along the polyline. The width of the cut must be flexible, it varies between 4 and 20 meters for different streets. Also, the height of the cut between DEM and street level is different along the polyline (see h1 and h2). The slope between P1 and P2 can be assumed as constant. I have the DEM (1 m resolution) and the lines, but nothing more.

[image]

I’m looking for a tool to perform such a cut out/burn in operation, preferably in ArcMap 10.x. I would prefer something automated, since I have 20-30 street polylines to cut/burn, but can also do it one by one per hand, if need be. I have access to ArcMap, but have no experience in programming (Python etc.).

Is there any solution that you can think of?

---

After using the solution of Hornbydd my result looked like this:

[image]

Comment: What data do you have? Lines and a dem? Do you want to modify the DEM or lines? Pick either ArcGIS or QGIS or your question will probably get closed

Comment: I have the DEM and the lines (Polyline Shapefile) and I want to modify the DEM.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the lines on top of the DEM (to be able to replicate similar data as yours)

Comment: If P1 end was say 100m and P2 end was 50m and for arguments sakes H1 position is 50% along the line then the desired elevation along the blue line at H1 would be 75m? So the Blue line is a constant slope or "plane"?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro, QGIS, GRASS and SAGA you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Screenshot added, rephrased problem description.

Comment: @Hornbydd: Question reopend. Please be so kind to share your solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a workflow that I will describe but you could easily do it in model builder to automate the processing. It requires you to have the Spatial Analyst extension and an *Advanced* license level.

Here is a hill shade of a DSM and a line. You will have identified the elevation at the line end vertices (P1 and P2 in your question). You could have done that manually or extracted the end vertices and used them to query the DSM. In my example the elevations are 147m and 157.6m

[image: Inputs]

**Step 1** - Create a buffer with flat ends (this uses the Advance license) to your required width.

[image: Buffer]

**Step 2** - Rasterize the line (polyline to raster tool), ensure same cell size as DSM and snap raster environment setting is set to the DSM.

[image: Raster polyline]

**Step 3** - Convert raster polyline to points (raster to points tool) and attribute with elevation. Now the raster to points will create a sequence, the first point being one end of the line. Add a new field of type double to the point dataset, call it "ele" for elevation. Work out the range of your elevation (e.g. P2 -P1) and divide that value by the number of points your raster line was made up of, for me that was (157.6 - 147) / 212 = 0.05. Do a field calculate and assign elevation along the points I used the simple equation of 147.6 + (0.05 * !pointid!). !pointid! is a the sequential ID number given to the point when you converted from raster to point.

[image: Assign elevation]

The result is a sequence of points stepping up in a constant values (so think of that as a constant plane) from P1 to P2

[image: Result of calculation]

**Step 4** - Create a Euclidean allocation raster. Use you point data, source field is pointid (not the ele), cell size as DSM, also set mask setting to your buffer polygon and snap raster to DSM. These environment settings are important and limit the extent of processing. End results are cells assigned the pointid.

[image: Euclid Allo]

**Step 5** - Convert Euclidean allocation raster to a point dataset and join the elevation in your point dataset created in step 3 (that ele field). You can use the Join Field tool.

[image: Join Field]

*Ooops! - The image above is slightly wrong, you should be joining your `ele` field with `pointid` to `grid_code`, I'm erroneously showing `pointid` to `pointid`*

Here are the points and the joined elevation values.

[image: Results]

**Step 6** - Convert the points back to raster, ensure cell size is DSM, snap raster to DSM

[image: result]

**Step 7** - Optionally run the Focal Statistics tool on the output of step 6 to smooth the raster otherwise you get a stepped appearance in the final raster.

[image: Focal stats]

**Step 8** - Mosaic your smoothed elevation raster into your DSM  to create the required end result.

[image: Final result]

Here is the mosaic symbolised as a hill shade and elevation symbology to allow the surface to be displayed.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd, that solved my problem! How do even come up with such a specific workflow? ;) There are two things I had to change in order to make it work for me: at step 3 my formula for the field calculation was "Elevation at each point = P1 – (elevation step * !pointid!)", because P1 was higher than P2 in my case. And at step 5 the join field for the input table was grid_code rather than pointid. Oher than that it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianH I guess its down to _years_ of fiddling around with the tools and watching/learning from others on GIS SE/esri forum. Also importantly you bothered to describe your problem with all the detail needed for someone like me to say "Ah! I can answer that". If you had not, then I suspect you would not have got an answer. I have added a warning message into my answer about the join, I think I must have defaulted to pointid although I would have used grid_code.